# Retrieving button value from another page in jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, button

I have the following jQuery to create a div element for each entry in the JSON array

```
var res = $('#videoContainer');
$.each(msg, function (index, e) {
    var newdiv = $('<form action = "makeNotes.html" method = "get"><button name="video"                
      value=' + e.ID + '><div class="videos">' + e.ID + e.Name + e.Directory + '<div></button></form>');
    res.append(newdiv);
});
```

On the action page "makeNotes.html" I want to get the value (e.ID) of the button that has been clicked on.

Could someone help me with the JQuery to do this? Excuse my poor knowledge of jQuery and please make suggestions if I have done the above code incorrectly too.

Thanks

Comment: Could you clarify your question?  It sounds like you want to get the id of the clicked button on the next page, but the button isn't type=submit.  Is the button supposed to cause you to navigate to the next page?  You might create a jsfiddle link as well, to illustrate what you're trying to do more clearly.

Comment: Yes when the button is clicked I want to be navigated to the next page, and have access to the 'value' field of the button selected

Answer (score 0):

Use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
res.on('click', 'form[action="makeNotes.html"] button', function () {
    alert(this.id);
});
```

[Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

[Attribute Equals Selector [name="value"]](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a jQuery problem--it sounds like an HTML forms problem.

I would suggest creating a second input element within the form: `<input type='hidden' name='videoId' value='" + e.ID + "'/>`

Also, instead of `<button ...>` you probably want `<input type='submit' ...>`